# I need a clear example for zeroMQ c++11 < > Python multipart messaging cvmat + string

Tags: python, opencv, c++11, zeromq

I can send and receive multipart messages with Python as shown below. May be my gentle touch or lack of concentration I couldn't make work c++11 < > Python messaging as same way.

Also didn't find a clear example.

What I need:

I have cv::Mat and string information. I want to send it to the Python (or c++11 no problem) through zeromq.

I think this could be very useful for all ZeroMQ users.

In python I can send and receive messages as below :

server.py (partly):

```
def send_array_and_str(socket, img, string, flags=0):
  global count

  md = dict(dtype=str(img.dtype), shape=img.shape)
  socket.send_string(str(count), flags | zmq.SNDMORE)
  socket.send_json(md, flags | zmq.SNDMORE)
  socket.send(img, flags)
  count += 1
  # print(count)
  return


context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5667")
time.sleep(0.2)
```

client.py (partly):

```
def recv_array_and_str(socket, flags=0, copy=True, track=False):
  string = socket.recv_string(flags=flags)
  md = socket.recv_json(flags=flags)
  msg = socket.recv(flags=flags, copy=copy, track=track)
  print('::', string)
  # print()
  img = np.frombuffer(bytes(memoryview(msg)), dtype=md['dtype'])
  return string, img.reshape(md['shape'])
```

Comment: I would love to see such example. zeromq a lot of examples in the github. but somehow not easily understandable. ** One more : what is the alternative option to communicate between c++11 and python  for string + cvMat *?

Comment: So, your Python code works as expected, but the C++ code doesn't? However, there's not a single line of C++ code above, so you're asking how to fix code that you didn't even show! Please read [ask]! Also, extract and provide a [mcve], i.e. two python programs successfully communicating with each other, along with your best attempt at a translation to C++.

Comment: PRoblem is i am not c++ expert. a humble starter and just need a working example to follow the steps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Zguide has a [list of example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:_start). If you want help using a specific pattern you will need to explain better what you are trying to do, what you tried, and what didn't work.